# How to schedule a airflow dag for multiple days?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

i'm trying to schedule a dag from 12pm on let's say 15/02/2024 to 12pm of 17/02/2024 and it runs every 3 hours, but when i'm using the following cron expression:
`0 12/3 * * *`

i have given the start date in the dag as 15/02/2024 and end date as 17/02/2024.
The dag here runs from 12pm 15/02/2024 to 12am 16/02/2024 and it again starts from 12pm on 16/02/2024.

How can i make the dag also run from 12am-12pm 16/02/2024 with an interval of 3 hours?

Comment: Just use `0 */3 * * *` with an appropriate `start_date` and `end_date`.

Answer (score 0):

The CRON instruction to use is the following `0 */3 * * *` in conjunction with using an appropriate `start_date` and `end_date`.

```py
DAG(
    dag_id="my_dag_name",
    start_date=datetime.datetime(2024, 2, 15, 12, 0),
    end_date=datetime.datetime(2024, 2, 17, 12, 0),
    schedule='0 */3 * * *',
    catchup=True,)
```

With this configuration, the DAG will generate [DAG runs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dag-run.html) for every time period included between the start date and the end date, using a 3 hours interval.

Turning on [catch up](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dag-run.html#catchup) mode allows to run the DAG for the whole period once activated.

You can use tools such as[crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#0_*/3_*_*_*) to design the CRON expression. You can click on the `next` button to have examples of the following executions.